# Sorting and paging nested documents

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch has out of the box support of sorting and pagination. But what if I want to retrieve only nested objects, paginate them and sort by it's field? 
For example:

```
{
  "mappings" : {
    "library" : {
      "properties" : {
        "name" : {"type": "string"},
        "books" : {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties" : {
            "title" : {"type": "string"},
            "author" : {"type": "string"},
            "year" : {"type": "integer"}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I ask Elasticsearch: "give me first 10 `books` with `offset = 20` with `title= 'Elasticsearch'` sorted by `year`"? Is it possible with nested type, or I should use slower parent-child relationship?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out that it's not possible to sort and paginate nested documents. This topic proves it https://discuss.elastic.co/t/nested-objects-hits-inner-hits-and-sorting/32565.

Comment: It's not possible and for the scope of this question, this is the correct answer.

As I did not get any other approach or answers awarding the bounty to this answer.

Cheers

Comment: Partial solution using composite aggregation and unique identifier for nested objects  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62589417/how-to-paginate-nested-objects-in-elasticsearch-without-offset

Answer (score 7):

Yes, that's possible, you can use [nested inner hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits) to achieve what you want:

```
POST index/library/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "nested" : {
            "path" : "books",
            "query" : {
                "match" : {"books.title" : "Elasticsearch"}
            },
            "inner_hits" : {
                "from": 20,
                "size": 10,
                "sort": {"books.year": "asc"}
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Val, `inner_hits` works, but it sorts (and paginates) nested objects only in scope of it's parent document. So if query result contains 2 `library` documents, each has sorted array with only it's own `books`, but what I want to achieve is one sorted array with all `books` matched. Is that possible?

Comment: What I would do is make the book object a top level one with an additional `library_name` field. No need for using `nested` type, unless you have other requirements that you haven't mentioned.

Comment: The real mappings are more complicated. We use `nested` to 'emulate' `has many` relashionship. We have documents that has several 'has many' fields (some of them has one as well). We don't change the data often, so `nested` would be fast solution. The only stoper is paging/sorting nested objects out of the parent's scope. If it's impossible - we have to look for the different solution. According to your previous comment I can't achive what I want with `nested`, right?