# How to paginate nested objects in Elasticsearch without offset?

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination

I would like to paginate over a nested array in Elasticsearch 7.X –– using `from` and `size` is not an option in this scenario and instead [search_after](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.8/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-search-after) or the [Scroll API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/scroll-api.html) would be preferred.

Considering the following (simplified) schema with a field `actions` as nested objects:

```
{
  "protocol" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "actions" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "properties" : {
            "data" : {},
            "timestamp" : {
              "type" : "date"
            },
            "type" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "user" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As the `actions` array could be in the realm of 15,000 - 20,000 entries, I would like to paginate over the entries instead of retrieving them all at once. I would only have to consider on document at a time, so there is no need to consolidate these entries across multiple documents.

I already tried using `inner_hits`, bucketing using a `date_histogram` of `log.timestamp` and a composite aggregation. However, I was not able to achieve the simple pagination I was looking for. Bucketing seemed to be a dead end, as I would have to retrieve **all** items within a bucket and not just an arbitrary number of `top_hits`.

**Any pointer in the right direction is highly appreciated, as I have been pulling my hair out over this already.**

Following is the nested query I used in conjunction with `inner_hits`:

```
POST protocol/_search
{
  "_source": "false", 
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "actions",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "_id": "<document-id>"
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  }
}
```

The above query yields the following result:

```
{
  "took" : 867,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : { ... },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "protocol",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "<document-id>",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : { },
        "inner_hits" : {
          "actions" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 30,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 1.0,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "protocol",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "<document-id>",
                  "_nested" : {
                    "field" : "actions",
                    "offset" : 0
                  },
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "actor" : "<user-id>",
                    "data" : {
                      ... // arbitrary non-indexed payload
                    },
                    "type" : "attach",
                    "timestamp" : "2020-06-24T06:34:00.665Z"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_index" : "protocol",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "<document-id>",
                  "_nested" : {
                    "field" : "actions",
                    "offset" : 1
                  },
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "actor" : "<user-id>",
                    "data" : {
                      ... // arbitrary non-indexed payload
                    },
                    "type" : "update",
                    "timestamp" : "2020-06-23T13:09:04.089Z"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_index" : "protocol",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "<document-id>",
                  "_nested" : {
                    "field" : "actions",
                    "offset" : 2
                  },
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "actor" : "<user-id>",
                    "data" : {
                      ... // arbitrary non-indexed payload
                    },
                    "type" : "update",
                    "timestamp" : "2020-06-23T13:08:58.695Z"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your inner hits query which you tried to help further.

Comment: @Gibbs Sure, I just added the query and exemplary response payload of my previous approach to the original question. Thanks for having a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple of failed approaches I have finally managed to solve this problem. Even though not the most elegant solution, the following composite aggregation creates an separate bucket for each individual item in the nested object. The buckets can then be retrieved in a paginated fashion.

```
POST protocol/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_id": "<document-id>"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "actionByUserAndTimestamp": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "actions"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "log": {
          "composite": {
            "size": 10,
            "sources": [
              {
                "actionByActor": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "actions.actor"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "actionByTimestamp": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "actions.timestamp"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "aggs": {
            "items": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The requirement of this solution is for the specified terms within the composite aggregation to be a unique combination. Otherwise, there will potentially be more than one item in a bucket, which then won't be considered due to the the top hits size limitation.